# How to pass and set a CGFloat by reference?

Tags: objective-c

I want to make an method which takes an CGFloat by reference.

Could I do something like this?

```
- (void)doStuff:(CGFloat*)floatPointer
```

I guess this must look different than other object pointers which have two of those stars. Also I'm not sure if I must do something like:

```
- (void)doStuff:(const CGFloat*)floatPointer
```

And of course, no idea how to assign an CGFloat value to that floatPointer. Maybe `&floatPointer = 5.0f;` ?

Could someone give some examples and explain these? Would be great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

objective-c is still c, so

```
-(void) doStuff (CGFloat *) f
{
  *f = 1.2;
}
```

call with

```
CGFloat f = 1.0;
[self doStuff:&f];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are passing a CGFloat by reference, then accessing it is simple:

```
- (void)doStuff:(CGFloat*)floatPointer {
    *floatPointer = 5.0f;
}
```

Explanation: as you are getting a reference, you need to de-reference the pointer (with the *) to get or set the value.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks. Why must I write the const keyword in front of CGFloat?

Comment: The const keyword says: "I pass you the reference to but you are not allowed to modify it".

Answer (score 2):

if you (hate pointers and ;-) prefer objective-c++ pass by reference, the following is an alternative:

```
-(void) doStuffPlusPlus:(CGFloat &) f
{
   f = 1.3;
}
```

call by

```
CGFloat abc = 1.0;
[self doStuffPlusPlus:abc];
```

and, you need to rename the source filename from ???.m to ???.mm